# Unable to click checkbox in Angular using Selenium Python

Tags: python, html, angular, selenium-webdriver, angular-material

I am trying to find a checkbox in my angular page and trying to click it. However, I am unable to do so for some reason I am unable to understand. The following is my code and below that is the error:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Edge
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

username = "XXXXXXXXX"
password = "XXXXXXXXX"

print (username)
print (password)

download_folder_path = "C:\\Users\\ggopakumar1\\Desktop\\Test"

url = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

prefs = {
    "download.default_directory": r"C:\Users\ggopakumar1\Desktop\Test\\",
    "excludeSwitches": ["disable-popup-blocking"],
    'user_experience_metrics':{'personalization_data_consent_enabled': True}
}

options = webdriver.EdgeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)

browser = webdriver.Edge(options = options) 
browser.get(url)


username_input = browser.find_element(By.ID,"username")
username_input.send_keys(username)

password_input = browser.find_element(By.ID,"password")
password_input.send_keys(password)
password_input.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.url_contains("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"))

browser.get("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")

WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(), 'txt')]"))).click()
print("Clicked the first element")

WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "mat-checkbox-28"))).click()
print("Clicked the second element")

WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(), 'Move')]"))).click()
print("Clicked the third element")

WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(), 'Email')]"))).click()
print("Clicked the fourth element")

WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='cdk-overlay-container']//span[contains(text(), 'Archive')]"))).click()

WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(), 'Move here')]"))).click()

time.sleep(10)

browser.quit()
```

This is the error I am receiving:

```
Clicked the first element
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ggopakumar1\EC_AD_Integration.py", line 56, in <module>
    checkboxButton = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "mat-checkbox-28")))
```

It works till the "Clicked the first element" part but it is not able to move forward. I have checked the ID of the checkbox and it is correct. And it doesn't work for me to find the label next to the checkbox as that performs a different function in the page. I have to find the checkbox itself and click it.

The following is the html code for the element:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFDmA.png)

Comment: How did you find 'I have checked the ID of the checkbox and it is correct.'? Please share your html.